How can I stop Pycharm from indexing ALL directories?
Lately I was searching on the internet for a solution for an issue we are having in our company.
We use AutoFS to mount NFS paths to our working machines (For example, home dirs), so it only mounts when using certain path.
Lets say the tree looks like this:
.
└── homes/
    ├── user1/
    │   ├── Desktop
    │   ├── Documents
    │   └── Pycharm/
    │       └── Projects
    ├── user2
    ├── user3
    └── user4

When Pycharm is opening and start indexing, even if I just want my home folder (user1), it triggers all mounts and causes my CPU to reach 100% and mount over 2000+ paths.
I think the main issue is that Pycharm is indexing the whole paths recursively and not just the top folder name.
Also, in official Pycharm system requirements it says: "A network file system such as NFS or SMB is not acceptable."
Is there an option to index only opened paths?
Did this ever happen to anyone?
Thanks!
I tried using different file chooser:
ide.ui.new.file.chooser=true
~/.config/JetBrains/<$PyCharmVersion$>/idea.properties
I tried to create a symlink to my home directory locally and then when opening in pycharm I open the local symlink, but sometimes it doesn't work.
